# How do I launch windows if I have installed Ubuntu?

Tags: windows

I have installed Ubuntu, and when I switch on PC it doesn't show me a screen of choosing OS. how could I make it appear?

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` command on terminal.

Comment: is it booting into windows or is it booting into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

**Install Boot-Repair on ubuntu by following steps**

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

After completing the installation you can launch it from System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu if you use Gnome, or search "boot-repair" in the dash if you use Unity. Then follow the following screenshots:

***Method 1***

- **Click on the advanced options**

[image: Initial screen]

- **Tick the options shown below**

[image: advanced option]

- **Change the tab to Grub Location Tab and Tick The options Shown in the figure**

[image]

**Press Apply and Reboot the system**

***Method 2***

- Select the recommended Boot repair options as shown in the first screenshot

Comment: thanks! actually i have installed Ubuntu instead of Windows, even though I chose installing it with Windows.